# How to extract summary() to a data frame applicable for data visualization in ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I am doing survival-analysis with the presence of `competing risks`. I use the `prodlim-package`, which I find quite useful. However, I do not like the build-in graphics, and would like to apply `ggplot` instead.

**Question:** how can I extract the `prodlim summary()`-output and load it into a data frame accessible to ggplot2?

Perhaps a function can be written to do this? I have previously received [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784714/write-a-summary-to-as-data-frame-for-use-in-ggplot-r) on StackOverflow in terms of loading a `summary()`-output into a `dataframe`, but with a different package than `prodlim`.

```
library(prodlim)
library(riskRegression)

# Build-in data
data(Melanoma)

# Simple competing risk analysis
fit.aj <- prodlim(Hist(time,status)~age+sex,data=Melanoma)

# Defining the event of interest as cause=1
summary(fit.aj,conf.int=FALSE,newdata=data.frame(age=50,sex="Male"),cause=1)
```

Which yields

```
> summary(fit.aj,conf.int=FALSE,newdata=data.frame(age=50,sex="Male"),cause=1)

----------> Cause:  1 

age=50, sex=Male :
  time n.risk n.event n.lost cuminc se.cuminc lower upper
1   10     33       0      0  0.000    0.0000 0.000 0.000
2 1513     22       0      0  0.282    0.0795 0.126 0.437
3 2006     15       0      0  0.282    0.0795 0.126 0.437
4 3042     10       0      0  0.396    0.0998 0.201 0.592
5 5565      0       0      0     NA        NA    NA    NA
```

The summary can easily be plotted; however, the graphics are not my style.

```
plot(fit.aj,conf.int=FALSE,newdata=data.frame(age=50,sex="Male"),cause=1)
```

[image]

I would like to convert the `summary()` into a `dataframe` (lets called it `df`), which can be included in `ggplot()`.

Based on the `names` in `summary()`, I am trying to achieve something like:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) +
geom_line(aes(y=cuminc) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You can check the source code to see how they extract the data for plotting https://github.com/cran/prodlim/blob/master/R/plot.prodlim.R

Comment: Hi @Tung - yes, I did consider that the solution probably lies herein. Unfortunately, that is way above my current skill level.

Comment: Have you already considered the `survival` and `survminer` package for survival curve generation? Their graphs are also quite nice

Comment: Here is a thread http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survminer-r-package-survival-data-analysis-and-visualization

Comment: Hi @Tjebo. Yes, `survminer` is very nice, however, it only work with binary outcomes. I am working with multistate models, which require packeges like `prodlim`. I would like to extract the `cuminc` data from `prodlim` at `times=c(1,2,3,4,5...)` so that data an be visualized in e.g. `ggplot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the resulting list up to the level where the table for the plot is found and save it as a data.frame. You can check the structure of the list by using `str`.

```
summ_list <- summary(fit.aj,conf.int=FALSE,newdata=data.frame(age=50,sex="Male"),cause=1)
df<-as.data.frame(summ_list $table$`1`$`age=50, sex=Male`)

#The desired plot with ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=cuminc)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, 
                              ymax = upper))
```

[image: ggplot]

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Thank you for the input. However, I am kinda looking for that continuous x-axis as in the `plot` uploaded in my Question, and not simply does printed in summary().

Comment: @cmirian how is this x axis not continuous?

Comment: Hi @Tjebo. The current approach only extract `cuminc` corresponding to `times=c(10,1513,2006,3042,5565)`. Perhaps continuous was a bit misleading. What I meant was, that I need times to be `c(1,2,3,4...)`